# asp.net web api - parameter binding with inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In the below code, employee is passed as null to the PostEmployee function. How can I get my input json that consists of Id, Name and EmployeeNumber, mapped correctly to Employee entity when it inherits from another entity.

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public string Id { get; set;}
}

public class Employee: Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
}

public HttpResponseMessage PostEmployee(Employee employee)
{
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try using Fiddler to pass an Employee JSON object back to the Web API. It looks strange that it doesn't map back to Employee object, because you are explicitly stating which object you are expecting. I am not sure that inheritance plays a big deal here.

Comment: Thanks, made an edit. Entity is an abstract class.

Comment: Regardless, you are expecting an object of type Employee, not Entity. Model binder should be aware of this.